# Excel Mass Function Change (Replacing from X to Y)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]
I want to mass-change the functions of this whole column to follow

`SUMIFS(($P$2:$P$49,$O$2:$O$49, "(Text)")`

To

`SUMIFS(($P$2:$P$49,$N$2:$N$49, "(Text)")`

Answer (score 0):

Just highlight the formulas then do a Find & Replace (Ctrl+H)

[image]

In your case replace $D with $O$49 and $C with $N$49 then hit replace all.
Make sure you have the Look in: Formulas set!

Answer (score 0):

and replace $O$2 with $N$2 please check 1 answer